# Moai: Clipping an image to a polygon

Tags: 2d, clipping

I'm using *Moai SDK*. I have an image and some random convex 2D polygons. I want to show only the parts of the image inside these polygons.

Here's an example image:

[image: sample image]

The same, shown only where the polygons are:

[image: same sample image, clipped to three polygons]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bottom left corner is (0,0) top right corner is (1,1). Create your polygons of what you want to show in this space, and your positions will be equal to your texture coordinates, then just render them as usual.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, this is achieved using a clipping mask and an multiply composite operation.

The specifics varies by framework, but with Moai the job is done by way of the [MOAIMultiTexture](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_multi_texture.html).

Comment: The efficiency of this solution would be terrible as you read each pixel twice, apply logic, and write. Also still requires calculating polygons to generate the mask itself from.

Comment: @MickLH: Composite operations are done in hardware, and are *fast*. Rasterizing the polygons to create a mask can also leverage hardware acceleration, and is also *fast*.

Comment: Well I didn't downvote ;) I did call it a solution, I just am an algorithms fetishist and can't ignore the fact that the process of generating the coverage mask could have just directly written the final image to the screen! --- What I should have said is that the general case is overkill here because he can simply rasterize polygons, your solution would be more suited to a curved cutout.

Comment: @MickLH: The solution is fundamentally the same as the one you propose; except that it's split into explicit stages. If the rendering is a one-off, your approach is probably faster, but if the scene is repeatedly rendered, not redoing the polygon rasterization (which has do be done no mattter what you do) can save cycles.

Comment: "not redoing the polygon rasterization (which has do be done no mattter what you do) can save cycles" yes, you may save a _few_ polygons cycles at the expensive of thousands of pixels which also cost cycles in the same chip. --- With respect to the application, the polygon count is constant where the number of pixels of the _mobile_ device will increase over time. This O(n) system is not going to outperform the O(1) system _that is a sub-step of the O(n) system_ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Create an image with the same resolution, make it completely opaque. 
Create some random set of polygons within the boundaries of the this image, set the opaqueness to 0 (so it's completely see through).

Here is an idea for creating the polygon with:

```
int noPolygons = whatever;

for (i = 0; i < noPolygons ; i ++) {
    int polygonPoints = whatever2;
    Vector points[polygonPoints ];
    float radius = whatever3;
    int centerX = random(0+radius, imageWidth-radius);
    int centerY = random(0+radius, imageHeight-radius);

    for (j = 0; j < polygonPoints ; j++) {
        float x     = cosinus(j/polygonPoints)*random(0.5, 1) * radius;            
        float y     = sinus(j/polygonPoints)*random(0.5, 1) * radius;

        points[j] = new Vector(centerX+x, centerY + y);
    }

    Edge edges[polygonPoints ];
    for (j = 0; j < polygonPoints ; j++) {
        int lastIndex = j + 1 >= polygonPoints ? 0 : j +1; 
        edges[j] = new Edge(points[j], points[lastIndex ]);  
    }  
}
```

This would produce fairly convex polygons, I think.

I hope Moai SDK supports these things, never used it.